# How to decrypt Hash Password in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I have google this alot, but unfortunatilty found no working solution.

I know its a bad technique, but I need to send user its password by email.

I have manage to sent user Hash password, but i am unable to decrypt this password.

The following is the procedure i am using.

```
    $results = DB::select("select * from dockl_users where email='" . Input::get('email')  ."';");      

                foreach($results as $data){
                $password=          $data->password;
                $email=             $data->email;

               }

            Mail::send('passwordRecovery', array('email' =>$password), function($message)
            {
                $message->to(Input::get('email') )->subject('Password Recovery');
            });
```

The above code send `Encrypted` password to the user by email but when i try to decrypt, it gives me following error message.

```
$decrypt= Crypt::decrypt($data->password);
```

> Invalid data.

```
throw new DecryptException("Invalid data.");
```

Kindly guide me how to achieve this..

Comment: A hash is *one-way* and provides no method for decryption. You should send the user a link to reset their password.

Comment: You shall never store user's literal password. Never, ever.

Comment: This is an impossible task.  Your passwords are *not* encrypted, they are hashed.  Encryption and hashing are two completely different things.  Hashing is a *one-way* operation.  There is no way to get the user's password from the hash.

Comment: so if i change the  password storing mechanism from hash to encrypt then its possible?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. DON'T, DON'T, DON'T, DON'T, DON'T do that. It's a major security issue.

Comment: @Kirmani88: If you change the password storing mechanism from hash to encrypt, then yes you can get back the user's password, but then you are creating an unsafe website.  Do not do that.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much for the guidance :)

Comment: If you do that we all *promise* to hack your site. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The fact that the code is prone to sql injection and the table name being revealed just makes hacking it much easier. All thats left is to find out the webiste url, and then its easy for the hacker to do anything they want to the website :D

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Short answer is that you don't 'decrypt' the password (because it's not encrypted - it's hashed).

The long answer is that you shouldn't send the user their password by email, or any other way. If the user has forgotten their password, you should send them a *password reset* email, and allow them to change their password on your website.

Laravel has most of this functionality built in (see the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#resetting-passwords) - I'm not going to replicate it all here. Also available for versions [4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#password-reminders-and-reset) and [5.0](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#password-reminders-and-reset) of Laravel).

For further reading, check out this 'blogoverflow' post: [Why passwords should be hashed](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/why-passwords-should-be-hashed/).

Answer (score 12):

For compare hashed password with the plain text password string you can use the PHP [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php)

```
if(password_verify('1234567', $crypt_password_string)) {
    // in case if "$crypt_password_string" actually hides "1234567"
}
```

Comment: In laravel it's better to use `Hash::check`.

Comment: Yes, Judge2020, seems you're right. Thank you. It's described in the: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing