# Encrypt decrypt Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to encrypt the password like this,

RegisterController:

```
'password' => encrypt($data['password']),
```

Then I need to decrypt the password during Forgot Password module.

MyController:

```
$pass = decrypt($password);
```

Everything works fine till now.

But when I try to login it throws the message:

```
These credentials do not match our records.
```

I think I need to make changes at Login controller but can't figure out exactly where.

How do I do that?

Comment: password should be hashed not encrypted as pointed by @Adhika, and its a very bad practice to be able to decrypt users password, its like having them in plain text. If you are able to decrypt any decent hacker should be able too. I will never register to a site knowing the admin is able to view my password.

Comment: Have you changed or re-generated your application key saved in .env or config/app.php file?

Answer (score 4):

You can't "decrypt" password because actually they are hashed (no way to get your plain text password back).

If you want to implement resetting password in your app, you can refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#resetting-passwords

Related answer on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/32701246/4504053